# input radio button hover issues in IE 9

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having a problem in IE9: **Whenever i hover over my *top level* wrapper div the first radio button acts like it's being hovered over**. So even if i have the last radio input pressed, if i click anywhere within the wrapper, the radio will go back to the first one. As soon as i hover my mouse off the wrapper div the light blue color on the first radio input changes back to gray as it should be.

[image]

My page works as expected in FF, Chrome and IE-Compatability mode.

I tried creating a simple page with inputs and can't recreate the problem as it's happening in my large web page.

Any input into what can be causing this and/or how to stop it would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit#1: mycode:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
...
<div id="region_sel_type">
    <input type="radio" id="optLine" name="radio_region_sel_type" value="Line" /><label id="lblForOptLine" for="optLine" title="Line" unselectable="on"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="optPoint" name="radio_region_sel_type" value="Point" /><label id="lblForOptPoint" for="optPoint" title="Point" unselectable="on"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="optPolygon" name="radio_region_sel_type" value="Polygon" /><label id="lblForOptPolygon" for="optPolygon" title="Polygon" unselectable="on"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="optList" name="radio_region_sel_type" value="List" /><label id="lblForOptList" for="optList" title="Input Coordinates" unselectable="on"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="optUploadKML" name="radio_region_sel_type" value="KML" /><label id="lblOptUploadKML" for="optUploadKML" title="Upload KML" unselectable="on"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="optOpen" name="radio_region_sel_type" value="Open" /><label id="lblForOptOptn" for="optOpen" title="Open Saved ROI" unselectable="on"></label>                   
</div> 
...
</div>
```

**SOLUTION:**
Somewhere inside the 'wrapper' div i had a self-closing label IE9 did not support (even though they should)

```
<label id='x'/>
```

Comment: Can you post the code for the div containing the radio buttons?

Comment: This sounds like something mistyped in your code.  Have you [validated](http://validator.w3.org/) the page?  The validator will catch some of the mistakes being mentioned in answers below.

Comment: Sparky's right! Validate your code. You could use [this](http://validator.w3.org/)

Comment: @Sparky: Shoot but the page has forms authentication. I'll try to remove authentication momentarily.

Comment: fixed all validation errors, still the same :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are describing is the behavior of the `label` tag.  Label tags act like a hover and click target for the input with the `id` specified in the label's `for` attribute.

Either you have inadvertently applied a large label to one specific radio button, or maybe one of them is incorrectly closed, causing it to wrap the whole `div`.

Have you checked all of your `label` tags to make sure none are incorrectly closed?

---

Now that you've got your problem solved, I thought I'd add a note about **self-closing tags in HTML 5** here.

XHTML started to tempt the world with XML strictness.  Now that we are in an HTML 5 world, it's easy to believe that's still true.  However, **HTML  5 doesn't know what `/>` is**.  Instead, it *tries to automatically close some tags for you.*

So in your case, it sounds like most browsers placed the implicit `</label>` at the expected place, but one browser placed it way out of context.  Either way, it's likely that none of them even cared about the `/>`.

Remember our old friend the `<p style="color:red;"><div>Why am I not red?</div></p>`?  HTML places the `</p>` before the `<div>` because block elements are not allowed inside `<p>` tags.

The best thing to do is just get out of the habit of using `/>` anywhere except elements that always have no content (`link`, `br`, `img`, etc. — and even then, you probably only want to do that for code readability, since in parsing, it makes absolutely no difference).

More info here: http://tiffanybbrown.com/2011/03/23/html5-does-not-allow-self-closing-tags/

Comment: Let me test this theory out. BRB

Comment: That seemed like a promising possibility, unfortunately i removed all the associated labels but the input keeps doing that. I then thought maybe i inadvertently have another label somewhere on the page with the FOR attribute pointing here. So deleted all the radio inputs except 2 and relabeled their "id" and "for" values. Still no luck.

Comment: @capdragon is it always the first one no matter what? What if you put another input, part of the same group, somewhere outside that div?

Comment: @Renesis: YES first one no matter what! Werid. The input outside that div still has the effect. So i put the first input (same group, just copy paste) outside the wrapper but it still does the hover thing when i hover over the wrapper div even though it's outside. Then i changed the "name"(group) and still same thing.

Comment: Okay: i figured it out... It was a self closed label on an above div somewhere like (<label id='x'/>) Which is weird because all browsers should support self-closing elements.

Comment: Awesome!  I've added a note about self-closing tags to the answer.